# Kindle: recovering credits for a book by removing it on a device?

Tags: kindle

I have reached the maximum number of devices authorized for the delivery of a Kindle ebook. However, I'm no more using one of the devices where I have delivered the book.
Is there a way to recover the credit for that book, in order to be used on another device?